# delay $.each() function with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, timing

Good day all.

I have this simple code:

```
totalTextArray = textForChatWithSeparators.split("#");    
    $.each(totalTextArray, function( index, value ) {           
    setTimeout(function(){console.log( value )},1000);
});
```

I expect to see in the console log, every second, the "`value`" logged, but instead I see all the log coming out in one block, after the delay of 1 second.

what i'm doing wrong? I'm thinking of the fact that a function inside the function could lead to some buffering problem?

Comment: Use `(index + 1) * 1000` instead of `1000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is

- make a call to `setTimeout` *n* times
- all *timeouts* will fire after `1000`ms together

What you would need to do if you don't want to change the structure is to increase the timeout value per iteration, like

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log( value ) },1000*index);
```

A probably more elegant (and more correct way imo), would be to change the structure of the loop all together. Using an interval-timer like

```
(function _loop( elem ) {
     console.log( elem );        

     if( totalTextArray.length ) {
         setTimeout( _loop.bind( null, totalTextArray.shift() ), 1000 );
     }
}());
```

Comment: you are right, i simply condensed all the timeouts after the 1st second. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is `closure`:

```
totalTextArray = textForChatWithSeparators.split("#");

$.each(totalTextArray, function(value, index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(value);
    }, 1000 * (index + 1));
});
```

EDIT:
I add more links about `closure`:

- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Comment: I think you've misread the question. The issue is that the timeouts all fire at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the index to interval time :|

Comment: But without using clousre, I am sure the `value` in log is wrong.

Comment: No, in this case since we already have a function-loop, we don't need to create another context. The anonymous loop function itself will create a new one per iteration.

Comment: Yep, I've just realized that. Thank you!